# phpmyadmin set timestamp timezone

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i login phpmyadmin at utc+8 place and the input 2019-12-27 00:00:00.000000 by timezone +8 to the "timestamp"
[image]
and

i login phpmyadmin at utc+0 place and the input 2019-12-27 00:00:00.000000 by timezone +0 to the "timestamp"
[image]

why does these two time are same?
even i change to different timezone VPS but display on phpmyadmin are same.

Comment: First of all you should not post images, also kindly refer to this [ask].

Comment: which plugin are you choosing for date picking?

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth I just click the data and display the date for me to choose. i insert two Same date but set different timezone, in phpmyadmin display are same

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the timezone in MySQL, just run this query:

```
SET SESSION time_zone = '+8:00';   //for current session

SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+8:00';    //for all sessions
```

The system time zone. When the server starts, it attempts to determine the time zone of the host machine automatically and uses it to set the system_time_zone system variable. The value does not change thereafter.

To explicitly specify the system time zone for MySQL Server at startup, set the TZ environment variable before you start mysqld. If you start the server using mysqld_safe, its --timezone option provides another way to set the system time zone. The permissible values for TZ and --timezone are system dependent.

[Reference Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html)

Comment: so phpmyadmin can not auto change to current timezone?, for example i login phpmyadmin at USA it can not auto change to usa timezone?

Comment: phpmyadmin changes the timezone of web server not of MySQL server.